# MySQL is not using keys on the outer query of a subselect with "IN"

Tags: mysql, performance, key, subquery

i'm querying a database like this:

```
 SELECT * from Log WHERE cookieId IN (select cookieId from Log WHERE someId="blafasel");
```

I have keys on someId and cookieId but yet the query is very slow.
If I run the two queries (the outer and the inner) separated both of them or very fast.

```
 select cookieId from Log WHERE someId="blafasel"
```

gets me the results almost instant. And so does a query

```
 SELECT * FROM Log WHERE cookieId IN ("something","somethingelse","athirdoption")
```

Using EXPLAIN tells me that keys are used in the two single queries but for the subselect query keys are only used for the inner select. My Question is why? And how to tell MySQL to be a little bit more clever.

Well I could let my application run the two queries separated but that wouldnt be convenient.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
SELECT  l.*
FROM    log l INNER JOIN
        log ls ON l.cookieid = ls.cookieid
WHERE   ls.someId="blafasel"
```

Comment: I was just a tad slower, so I deleted my answer stating the same and voted you up instead :p.

Comment: Nice, I'll use this to enhance some of my SQL queries.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply this?

```
SELECT * from Log WHERE someId="blafasel";
```

I imagine your real query is a bit different, but just in case it's not.

Also, does explain show the correct key in the "possible keys" column? If so, you could try using a "force index(index_name)" clause on the outer select to see if that speeds it up.

Answer (score 0):

Further (interesting) references:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9090
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/subquery-restrictions.html